# How to Put UIView subview In Places

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

For Example lets say I have a UIView I would like to display

```
view.addSubview(line)
```

Now I want t to be able to display that UIView in the top right corner. Let say inside the right side of the navigation bar. How would I do this? Or even in a specific place.

Comment: can you show the UI which type of the output you expec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to calculate the frame or need to give constraints to that view.

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

From above you can get screenwidth and you can set your y to 0. Let say width height of your view is 20. So, frame would be like below.

```
yourView.frame = CGRect(x:screenwidth - 20 , y: 20, width:20 , height: 20)
```

You can change the frame as per your requirements.

For navigation bar there is a better way to do it by adding right bar item. Look below code how to do it.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem
```

Comment: are you seen this `inside the right side of the navigation bar.`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Oh i missed that

Answer (score 0):

Add a frame for your subview, as :

**Objective-C:**

```
line.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

**Swift 3:**

```
CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 50,height: 50)
```

This will add your line subview on top left corner with height 50 and width 50.

Comment: Swift 3:   CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 50,height: 50)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @nil. Adding swift part to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`self.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: lineMat)`

to set up a view on navigationBar right side.

Also you can add the `lineMat` view on `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

Just use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(lineMat)` and set up to `lineMat` view's frame.